# Ionic button on-tap with long duration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTap/)

> on-tap
>
> Quick touch at a location. If the duration of the touch goes
> longer than 250ms it is no longer a tap gesture.

How to trigger event in case user presses the button, holds for more than 250ms, and releases it (while the finger is still in the button area)?
I tried on some native apps, the event is triggered but not in ionic app (on-tap, ng-click).

Hence the ionic button does not feel native.
Is there a normal way to work around this issue?

Comment: have you tried the on-hold directive? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/

Comment: I tried it, the event will be fired after 500ms even if the button is not released yet.

Comment: ok i see, did u try on-release as well? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onRelease/

Comment: I tried it, the event will be fired even if the finger is moved out of the button area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable swipe back on `ion-nav-view`:

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider){
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in ionic have an on-hold event:

```
<button on-hold="onHold()" class="button">Test</button>
```

here you can read the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/)

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 2/3 you can use the "**press**" event.

```
<button ion-button type="button" (press)="myAction()">My Button</button>
```